# Trace of Linear Transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I need to find the trace of the following powers of linear transformation which is already given.
[image]

My doubt is that Is there any better way than finding the matrix of linear transformation and then taking it's powers.
 Because it will involve quite a lot of calculation as we will have a 10× 10 matrix.
Am I missing any trick??
Thanks and regards.

Comment: Try computing eigenvalues. Note that there are some relatively obvious invariant subspaces, such as $\operatorname{span}(1)$, $\operatorname{span}(X, X^2)$, $\operatorname{span}(X^3, X^4, X^5)$ and $\operatorname{span}(X^6, X^7, X^8, X^9)$. You can break these subspaces down to eigenspaces without too much hassle.

Comment: Or, given that this transformation just permutes monomials, computing powers is pretty easy to do.

Comment: It will be helpful if you can elaborate a bit as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a 10x10 matrix indeed, but a really specific one.

Hint: Note that

- $T(a_0)=a_0$
- $X$ and $X^2$ coefficients are "mixed up"
- So are $X^3$, $X^4$ and $X^5$ coefficients
- Same with $X^i, i\in \{6,\ldots,9\}$

Treat each "block" separatly, and arrange them to form a [block diagonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_diagonal_matrices)

Comment: We need to evaluate powers of these diagonal blocks@F.Carette right??

Comment: You're right. And as theses are just permutations, a block to the right power will be nothing more than the identity matrix.